# How to extract namespace from XSD?

Tags: xml, groovy, xsd

I have an XSD that I want to use in serializing my domain objects into XML.  I'm using StreamingMarkupBuilder to generate the XML, but I want to be able to extract namespaces out of the XSD to use in building the XML.  Most examples I've seen either don't utilize an XSD, create JAXB classes from the XSD, or only use the XSD for validation.  I figure there's a Groovy way to process an XSD to extract namespace information for creating an XML, but I haven't found it.  Any ideas?

```
def xmlBuilder = new StreamingMarkupBuilder()
def xmlString = xmlBuilder.bind {
  mkp.declareNamespace(ns: extractedFromXSD)
  ...
```

Comment: Can you post your xsd?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are using `XmlParser` to get info from your XSD. To get the namespace, you instantiate the `XmlParser` [without validation neither namespace-awareness](http://prystash.blogspot.com.br/2009/09/groovy-xml-retrieve-namespace-of-nested.html): `new XmlParser(false, false)`.

I used a stripped [xsd example](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_example.asp) from w3schools:

```
xml = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="shiporder">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="orderperson" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="orderid" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>'''

xsd = new XmlParser(false, false).parseText xml

assert xsd.'@xmlns:xs' == 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'
```